# Using Spring DAO's NamedParameterJDBCTemplate, how can I code for multi column IN statement?

Tags: sql, spring, jdbctemplate, multiple-columns

How can `NamedParameterJDBTemplate` be used to retrieve for a sql query like below?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 
WHERE
    (COLUMN_1, COLUMN2) IN
    ((Val1, val2), (Val3, Val4));
```

Single column IN statements are easy to code in Spring DAO; but have not been able to find a solution for multi column IN.

Answer (score 2):

By adding parameter this way, you can add multiple value in `IN`:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("column1", Arrays.asList("Val1", "val2"));
parameters.addValue("column2", Arrays.asList("Val3", "Val4"));
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query("select * from TABLE_1 where (COLUMN_1, COLUMN2) in (:column1,:column2)",parameters,new Mapper());
```

Look at this [tuts](http://pure-essence.net/2011/03/16/how-to-execute-in-sql-in-spring-jdbctemplate/) too.

Answer (score 0):

Akash Rajbanshi answer is wrong, because of it will create query like

```sql
select * from TABLE_1 where (COLUMN_1, COLUMN2) in ("Val1","val2"), ("Val3", "Val4")
but we need 
select * from TABLE_1 where (COLUMN_1, COLUMN2) in ("Val1","Val3"), ("val2", "Val4")
```

Also, if we want to have more than 2 arguments it fails with exception

> ERROR: unequal number of entries in row expressions. It tries to make ((?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?))

So I figure it out with my own implementation for 2 column in statement. It makes pair of parameters and append to `StringBuilder` construction like `((?,?),(?,?),...,(?,?))`

```sql
public static <K, V> Pair<StringBuilder, Object[]> makeInQuery(StringBuilder sqlBuilder , Collection<Pair<K, V>> pairs) {
sqlBuilder.append("(");
Object[] params = new Object[pairs.size() * 2];
int i = 0;
for (Pair<K, V> pair : pairs) {
    if (i > 0) {
        sqlBuilder.append(",");
    }

    sqlBuilder.append("(?,?)");
    params[i] = pair.getFirst();
    params[i + 1] = pair.getSecond();
    i = i + 2;
}
sqlBuilder.append(")");

return new Pair<>(sqlBuilder, params);
}
```

And than we use `jdbcTemplate`

```
public ReturnSomething findByNodes(Collection<Pair<UUID,UUID>> fromToPairs) {
    StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder(BEFORE_IN_STATEMENT);
    Pair<StringBuilder, Object[]> sqlParamsPair = makeInQuery(sqlBuilder, fromToPairs);
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sqlParamsPair.getFirst().toString(), sqlParamsPair.getSecond(), entityMapper);
}
```